# How to get number of physical CPU:s in Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux

I am aware that `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` will give me the number of logical processors. But how can I get the number of physical processors?

Answer (score 3):

@Havoc P:
offline cpus aren't shown in /proc/cpuinfo .

CPU topology is described by /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/topology/*

Answer (score 1):

You could parse /proc/cpuinfo and count the number of distinct "physical id:" lines. Sort of annoying, but I don't know if there's a better option. If you're using GLib or another library with regex support it'd be easier. Or you could popen() a command line to do it if you're feeling really hacky.  example command line at: http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Understanding_proc_cpuinfo.html

Comment: POSIX regex support (BRE and ERE) is part of the standard library on any POSIX system, including Linux. No need for glib.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get this information is to use hwloc: http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/.

They provide a bunch of user tools that let you get at the cpu topology of a system, but they also provide a library that you can use from C: http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.1.1/#interface

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901694/programatically-detect-number-of-physical-processors-cores-or-if-hyper-threading/3082553#3082553) to a similar question does help. There's a comment about the code not being correct, but it could be a good starting point.