# Requesting integer multiple of "M" cores per node on SGE

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, hpc, sungridengine

I want to submit a multi-threaded MPI job to SGE, and the cluster I am running in has different nodes that each has different number of cores. Let's say the number of threads per process is M (M == `OMP_NUM_THREADS` for OpenMP) How can I request that a job submitted to a SGE queue would be run in a such a way that in every node, an integer multiple of M is allocated for my job?

Let's say M=8, and the number of MPI tasks is 5 (so a total of 40 cores requested). And in this cluster, there are nodes with 4, 8, 12, and 16 cores. Then this combination is OK:

```
2*(8-core nodes) + 1*(16-core nodes) + 0.5*(16-core nodes)
```

but of course not any of these ones:

```
2*(4-core nodes) + 2*(8-core nodes) + 1*(16-core node)
2*(12-core nodes) + 1*(16-core node)
(3/8)*(8-core nodes) + (5/8)*(8-core nodes) + 2*(16-core node)
```

PS: There was another similar question, like this one: ( [MPI & pthreads: nodes with different numbers of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755687/mpi-pthreads-nodes-with-different-numbers-of-cores) ), but mine is different since I have to run exactly M threads per MPI process (think hybrid MPI+OpenMP).

The best scenario is to run this job exclusively on the same kind of nodes. But to speed up the start time, I want to allow this job to run on different kind of nodes, provided that each node has integer*M cores allocated to the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The allocation policy in SGE is specified on per *parallel environment* (PE) basis. Each PE could be configured to fill the slots available on the cluster nodes in a specific way. One requests a specific PE with the `-pe pe_name num_slots` parameter and then SGE tries to find `num_slots` slots following the allocation policy of the `pe_name` PE. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to request slots in integer multiples per node.

In order to be able to request **exactly** `M` slots per host (and not a multiple of `M`), your SGE administrator (or you, in case you are the SGE administrator) must first create a new PE, let's call it `mpi8ppn`, set its `allocation_rule` to `8`, and then assign the PE to each cluster queue. Then you have to submit the job to that PE with `-pe mpi8ppn 40` and instruct the MPI runtime to start only one process per host, e.g. with `-npernode 1` for Open MPI.

If the above is unlikely to happen, your other (unreliable) solution would be to request a very high amount of memory per slot, close to what each node has, e.g. `-l h_vmem=23.5G`. Assuming that the nodes are configured with `h_vmem` of 24 GiB, this request will ensure that SGE won't be able to fit more than one slot on each host. So, if you would like to start a hybrid job on 5 nodes, you will simply ask SGE for 5 slots and 23.5G `vmem` for each slot with:

```
qsub -pe whatever 5 -l h_vmem=23.5G <other args> jobscript
```

or

```
#$ -pe whatever 5
#$ -l h_vmem=23.5G
```

This method is unreliable since it does not allow you to select cluster nodes that have a specific number of cores and only works if all nodes are configured with `h_vmem` of less than 47 GB. `h_vmem` serves just as an example here - any other per-slot consumable attribute should do. The following command should give you an idea of what host complexes are defined and what their values are across the cluster nodes:

```
qhost -F | egrep '(^[^ ])|(hc:)'
```

The method works best for clusters where `node_mem = k * #cores` with `k` being constant across all nodes. If a node provides twice the number of cores but also has twice the memory, e.g. 48 GiB, then the above request will give you two slots on such nodes.

I don't claim to fully understand SGE and my knowledge dates back from the SGE 6.2u5 era, so simpler solutions might exist nowadays.