# VS2012 support for __asm__ __volatile__ assembler code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, assembly

I´m using VS2012 C++ Windows 7 and I need to get information about CPU multithreading to calculate the number of available logic processors.

I´m using this code (from [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901694/programatically-detect-number-of-physical-processors-cores-or-if-hyper-threading/%22link%22))

```
typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;

uint32_t registers[4];
__asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid " :
                      "=a" (registers[0]),
                      "=b" (registers[1]),
                      "=c" (registers[2]),
                      "=d" (registers[3])
                      : "a" (1), "c" (0));

unsigned CPUFeatureSet = registers[3];
bool hyperthreading = CPUFeatureSet & (1 << 28);
```

This assembly does not compile, given the following error:

```
error C2065: '__asm__' : undeclared identifier
```

I´ve tried changing to `__asm __volatile` and putting everything in a single line as:

```
__asm __volatile ("cpuid " :   "=a" (registers[0]), "=b" (registers[1]), "=c" (registers[2]), "=d" (registers[3])  : "a" (1), "c" (0));
```

This did not work also, leading to:

```
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '('
```

Help appreciated to solve that.

Comment: That's gcc syntax, it won't work in VS like that. You will need to `mov` the inputs and outputs yourself, but I would be surprised if here was no winapi function you could just call to get this information.

Comment: Buf... I can´t write assembler... Where should the `mov` goes to ?

Comment: Also the syntax is entirely different. Look it up on MSDN.

Comment: Besides it being _GCC_ inline assembly templates that won't work with MSVC++, the other issue is that the _ASM_ inline assembly isn't available when developing 64-bit applications.You can create separate object files built using _MASM_, but inline assembler in 64-bit code isn't allowed.See Jester's answer for a solution using compiler intrinsics. In your case you could be creatinging 32-bit program but __ asm__ isn't an MSVC keyword, although *__asm* is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the architecture of the current machine, including processor and core count, and NUMA architecture, using the provided APIs.

- GetProcessorCount: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470844.aspx
- GetSystemInfo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx
- IsProcessorFeaturePresent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724482(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which one gives me Number of `Processors Cores` and `Number of Logic Processors` as shown in Windows 10 Task Management->Performance ???

Comment: You can also use [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on using cpuid, you should use the `__cpuid()` intrinsic function. The [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx) even comes with sample code. Something like this:

```
#include <intrin.h>

void foo()
{
    uint32_t registers[4];
    __cpuid(registers, 1);
    unsigned CPUFeatureSet = registers[3];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And there is an ``__cpuidex`` as well if you need to get to the CPUID extensions that require the sub function in ``ECX``