# Multicore CPUs, Different types of CPUs and operating systems

Tags: operating-system, cpu, multicore

An operating system should support CPU architecture and not specific CPU, for example if some company has Three types of CPUs all based of x86 architecture,
one is a single core processor, the other one a dual core and the last one has five cores, The operating system isn't CPU type based, it's architecture based, so how would the kernel know if the CPU it is running on supports multi-core processing or how many cores does it even have....

also for example Timer interrupts, Some versions of Intel's i386  processor family use PIT and others use the APIC Timer, to generate periodic timed interrupts, how does the operating system recognize that if it wants for example to config it... ( Specifically regarding timers I know they are usually set by the BIOS but the ISR handles for Timed interrupts should also recognize the timer mechanism it is running upon in order to disable / enable / modify it when handling some interrupt )

Is there such a thing as a CPU Driver that is relevant to the OS and not the BIOS?, also if someone could refer me to somewhere I could gain more knowledge about how Multi-core processing is triggered / implemented by the kernel in terms of "code" It would be great

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID ?

Comment: This diffidently helps me understand some things yet I've read in the past that in order to detect multi-core mechanism  some other weird memory scanning method is used

Comment: Yes, there is no single "give me the count of cores" instruction, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901694/programatically-detect-number-of-physical-processors-cores-or-if-hyper-threading

Answer (score 1):

The operating system kernel almost always has an abstraction layer called the **HAL**, which provides an interface above the hardware the rest of the kernel can easily use. This HAL is also **architecture-dependent** and not **model-dependent**. The CPU architecture has to define some invokation method that will allow the HAL to know about which features are present and which aren't present in the executing processor.

---

On the IA32/64 architecture, the is an instruction known as `CPUID`. You may ask another question here:

**Was CPUID present from the beginning?**

No, `CPUID` wasn't present in the earliest CPUs. In fact, it came a lot later with the developement in i386 processor. The 21st bit in the EFLAGS register indicates support for the `CPUID` instruction, according to Intel Manual Volume 2A.

```
PUSHFD
```

Using the  `PUSHFD` instruction, you can copy the contents of the EFLAGS register on the stack and check if the 21st bit is set.

**How does CPUID return information, if it is just an instruction?**

The CPUID instruction returns processor identification and feature information in the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers. Its output depends on the values put into the EAX and ECX registers before execution.

Each value (which is valid for CPUID) that can be put in the EAX register is known as a CPUID leaf. Some leaves have subleaves, .i.e. they depend on an sub-leaf value in the ECX register.

**How is multi-core support detected at the OS kernel level?**

There is a standard known as ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) which defines a set of ACPI tables. These include the **MADT** or *multiple APIC descriptor table*. This table contains entries that have information about local APICs, I/O APICs, Interrupt Redirections and much more. Each local APIC is associated with only one logical processor, as you should know.

Using this table, the kernel can get the APIC-ID of each local APIC present in the system (only those ones whose CPUs are working properly). The APIC id itself is divided into topological Ids (bit-by-bit) whose offsets are taken using CPUID. This allows the OS know where each CPU is located - its domain, chip, core, and hyperthreading id.